# split line in scala keeping first element of line common

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scala-collections

I am trying to split my data file in a following way.

```
1 1#1097#2321#2018
2 12#312#123#1211
```

So I want the resulting RDD to be:

```
1 1
1 1097
1 2321
1 2018
2 12
2 312
2 123
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already have your lines as an RDD (and there are no possible errors in input, on which I wouldn't count, so you may add some pre-validation/filtering):

```
lines.flatMap { case line =>
  val Array(head, other) = line.split(" ")
  other.split('#').map(o => head -> o)
}
```

Comment: And what if I want to split my lines #*
#@N
#t2
#cN
#index6666
#%15
#%487
#%925
#!abcdefff                             (Output should be (6666,15),(6666,487),                    (6666,925))

Comment: @rp2105, can you format the code? I don't get the question as it's stated now.

Comment: Sir, Please check below answer for proper format. Thanks.

Comment: (This is my line) And lines are seperated by "#(star*)". I have changed Spark-defaults.conf for that. So, basically my line starts with "#(star*)". Output should be-(6666,15),(6666,487), (6666,925),(7777,145),(7777,565),(7777,123),(7777,3695),(7777,4870)

Comment: Sir, my post has been deleted from below. And I am totally stuck. Please help me. I have customize the record delimiter to be“#*” instead of the new line character. By doing modification in spark-default.conf. So my every line in RDD is starting with "#*".